# R: find rows in data frame within range of each other across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID   lat   long   score
1    41.5  -62.3  22.4
2    41.0  -70.2  21.9
3    42.2  -63.0  22.7
4    36.7  -72.9  20.0
5    36.2  -62.4  24.1
6    35.8  -61.7  24.7
7    40.8  -61.9  22.1
```

I would like to identify rows of this data frame for which values for lat are within 1 unit of each other AND values for long are within 1 unit of each other AND values for score are within 0.7 units of each other. To indicate which rows meet these conditions, I'd like to add a new column (ID.matches) that provides values for ID for rows meeting the above conditions. The final data frame could look something like this:

```
ID   lat   long   score   ID.matches
1    41.5  -62.3  22.4    3, 7
2    41.0  -70.2  21.9    0
3    42.2  -63.0  22.7    1
4    36.7  -72.9  20.0    0
5    36.2  -62.4  24.1    6
6    35.8  -61.7  24.7    5
7    40.8  -61.9  22.1    1
```

I'm not really sure where to start with this...I think some sort of conditional function using dplyr or sapply? I'm also not sure if another data structure should be used for ID.matches, since some rows will have more than one match.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what would happen if row 1 and row 2 matched, and row 2 and row 3 matched, but row 1 and row 3 didn't match? This would happen if the points were on a straight line and each spaced 0.75 units apart. Would they all be in the same group?

Comment: Good point @Allan Cameron. Perhaps the group column I was thinking about isn't the best approach. It might instead be more effective to list all rows matching a particular row. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check all the conditions using `outer` to form a logical matrix (remembering to exclude the self-matching diagonal), and `apply` the result to subset the ID column, pasting the result together into strings:

```r
df$ID.matches <- apply(outer(df$lat,   df$lat,   function(x, y) abs(x - y) <   1) &
                       outer(df$lon,   df$lon,   function(x, y) abs(x - y) <   1) &
                       outer(df$score, df$score, function(x, y) abs(x - y) < 0.7) &
                       diag(nrow(df)) == 0, 
                       MARGIN = 1,
                       function(x) paste(df$ID[x], collapse = ", "))
df
#>   ID  lat  long score ID.matches
#> 1  1 41.5 -62.3  22.4       3, 7
#> 2  2 41.0 -70.2  21.9           
#> 3  3 42.2 -63.0  22.7          1
#> 4  4 36.7 -72.9  20.0           
#> 5  5 36.2 -62.4  24.1          6
#> 6  6 35.8 -61.7  24.7          5
#> 7  7 40.8 -61.9  22.1          1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: How would I add a conditional statement to this? In my example, I have a grouping variable that I only want to perform this function within. I don't want matches outside of the group

Answer (score 2):

A different approach using some of the `tidyverse` functions to `filter` to the rows matching the criteria and `pull` the `ID`s of the matching rows.

```
# Create example data
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~ID,   ~lat,   ~long,   ~score,
1,    41.5,  -62.3,  22.4,
2,    41.0,  -70.2,  21.9,
3,    42.2,  -63.0,  22.7,
4,    36.7,  -72.9,  20.0,
5,    36.2,  -62.4,  24.1,
6,    35.8,  -61.7,  24.7,
7,    40.8,  -61.9,  22.1
)
```

```
df$ID.match <- sapply(df$ID, function(x){
  
  df %>%
    filter(abs(lat- lat[ID == x]) < 1,
           abs(long - long[ID == x]) < 1,
           abs(score - score[ID == x]) < 0.7,
           ID != x) %>%
    pull(ID) %>%
    paste0(collapse = ',')
  
})


df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>      ID   lat  long score ID.match
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1     1  41.5 -62.3  22.4 "3,7"   
#> 2     2  41   -70.2  21.9 ""      
#> 3     3  42.2 -63    22.7 "1"     
#> 4     4  36.7 -72.9  20   ""      
#> 5     5  36.2 -62.4  24.1 "6"     
#> 6     6  35.8 -61.7  24.7 "5"     
#> 7     7  40.8 -61.9  22.1 "1"
```

Edit: here is how it can be done without using `sapply` and `$` (i.e. fully in the `tidyverse` framework)

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID.match = map_chr(ID, function(x){
    
    df %>%
      filter(abs(lat- lat[ID == x]) < 1,
             abs(long - long[ID == x]) < 1,
             abs(score - score[ID == x]) < 0.7,
             ID != x) %>%
      pull(ID) %>%
      paste0(collapse = ',')
    
  }))
```

Comment: How would I add a group by to this? I tried doing it above the filter call but it isn't working. Essentially I want to perform this function within groups, not being able to match outside of groups